# How to clone MicroSD Card Linux boot drive?

Tags: linux, clone, dd

I have a Lubuntu installation booting from a MicroSD card. I want to clone the bootable MicroSD card so that I can restore it to another card if it fails at some stage in the future. Will the command below create a bootable image which I can restore to a new SD card in the future?

```
sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk3 of=SD.img bs=1m
```

Answer (score 0):

If the card is `/dev/rdisk3` then yes, it will.

Just don't do it from under the said Lubuntu. Cloning mounted filesystem is a bad idea, unless it's mounted read-only.

To restore from the image, invoke something like `sudo dd if=SD.img of=/dev/rdisk3`. Again, don't do it when the card filesystem is mounted.

In general you almost always need a second Linux to easily clone the first.

Comment: with read-only snapshots you can clone running system :)

Comment: *"If the card is /dev/rdisk3 ..."* -- Presumably you are stipulating that the OP needs to copy from the whole SDcard rather than a partition?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the fdisk output for the MicroSD card, presumably the command should be:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sde of=SD.img bs=1m
```

?

```
Disk /dev/sde: 14.9 GiB, 15931539456 bytes, 31116288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x437cca03

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sde1  *        2048 23060479 23058432   11G 83 Linux
/dev/sde2       23062526 31115263  8052738  3.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sde5       23062528 31115263  8052736  3.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```